# Issue:Test In Web Chat in Azure Bot Service

Tags: azure, botframework, azure-bot-service

I am working on Microsoft Bot Framework, I am created the bot through Azure Bot Service in Azure Portal. When I am running my bot application in local emulator its working fine after that published into Azure Bot service.

[image]

Here my issue is whenever to test my application in in Azure Portal at **Test In Web Chat** option the test window will showing like this below.

[image]

Added the same bot to Skype channel there also I am not getting any response.

How can I resolve the problem?

Comment: What is your BotHandle?

Comment: My BotHandle name is ServiceMaxIot

Comment: I cannot find a bot with a handle of ServiceMaxlot in our logs.  I'm not looking for the Display Name, but the Bot Handle in settings.

Comment: Its a client bot we don't want to revel the name of the BotHandle. If you have to possible please provide your mail-id I will send the details of bot with you

Comment: My work email is on my profile: https://stackoverflow.com/users/86646/eric-dahlvang?tab=profile

Answer (score 0):

Please check your `MicrosoftAppID` and `MicrosoftAppPassword` are correctly mentioned in both your `BotApplication` as well as in `Azure Bot Service`. Also do check if the same is deployed properly and the `MessagingEndpoint` is correctly mentioned.

If this was just an issue with the channel your *Test in WebChat* could have worked properly.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion and I am provided correct details in my both BotApplication as well as in Azure Bot Service and also checked the same deployed properly at my MessageingEndPoint also.

Comment: You can try logging your application(store it in a blob). This might help you get a better idea of the issue. Helped me, when I created my bot !

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, it is happen to me with the same situation. I think you select publish as Website. You should select publish as Deployment Script.

Comment: Thanks for your replay and I can't understand how deploy through Script and when I am searching the same I am not able to get any reference URL. Could you please explain how to publish as  Deployment Script.